How to forward http requests made to local ip address to a cloud url
I have made a Samsung SmartThings Edge driver that runs on the SmartThings Hub. However, the problem is that the hub can only make LAN requests. I want to make a request to the internet, which I can achieve by running a server on the LAN that sends the request on behalf of the hub. But the requirement is such that we cannot run the server on the LAN. Is there a way to forward any request made to http://172.16.0.77:3000/ to https://somecloudapi.com/ from the router itself?
‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎

What have you tried so far?  StackOverflow expects you to try to solve your own problem first, as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with a [mcve]. For more information, please see [ask].
